# Is there a way to silence all css styles of a page?

Tags: javascript, css

I got a css sheet that is basically an ad (gray out all screen, box in the middle with ad contents, cant click anywhere but the "ad box").

I want to make it like so - if the user comes to my website, and a cookie isnt set, i load my "ad css" sheet on top of my index page (So i would have my ad in the middle, and then the rest of the website is grayed out). Once the user closes the "ad", the css sheet disappears, and my website works the same as it would without loading any "ad css" sheets.

My current problem is that once i load my "ad" css sheet, it messes up (for example images that im loading arent fitting in the div) because of the css sheets of the website.

Is it possible to silence all other css sheets but the "ad" sheet when loading the ad? Or maybe any other suggestions on what i should do?

Comment: This sounds like you're being too broad with your CSS Selectors, but I'll remind you that there is a _disabled_ property... [The attribute seems to be ignored in my test](http://jsbin.com/ayarac/1/edit)?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're being too broad with your CSS selectors if you're effecting more than you want with them, however

> Is it possible to silence all other css sheets but the "ad" sheet when loading the ad?

Yes, both [*HTMLStyleElement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLStyleElement)s and [*StyleSheet*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/stylesheet)s have a property called *disabled* that, when set *true*, effectively "turns them off". [`<style>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/style) elements are supposed to have an attribute that does the same, however [I've found it doesn't seem to be enforced](http://jsbin.com/ayarac/1/edit).

Therefore, to use this knowledge, simply loop over all `<style>` elements (via e.g. `document.getElementsByTagName('style')`) and set `.disabled = true`, or `false` to re-enable them.